# Query Result message returns 0 rows but browser shows results

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute, filter

I am using the Layer filter tools in QGIS version 3.14.1 Pi. (Right Click on layer > Filter)
The source data is a Mapinfo `.tab`-file on a Server.

When I put in my filter query, `"Field_name" LIKE 'value'` and I run the <kbd>Test</kbd> button, i get the popup message

> The where clause returned 0 row(s)

If I hit <kbd>OK</kbd> and essentially save that query onto the layer, and then browse the data in the attribute table, the table is filtered and rows are returned.

This is suggesting that the popup message, and the actual filter results are disconnected and is possibly a bug?

Can someone please verify this also before I log a bug or let me know if I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any issue with Filter in QGIS 3.14.16-Pi. When I run Test, I receive a message with correct results.

[image]

The message returns three records directly after click on `Test`, and when I click OK button, I got the same results in the attribute table.

Try to update your QGIS 3.14.1-Pi to the latest version which is 3.14.16-Pi, as it seems there is no issue in this version.